# Search a series of data in a column

Tags: database

I have simply two columns. In column A, series of 8000 rows like the following example:

A230399

**A230405**

A230407

A230418

A230827

**A233273**

A234868

A234905

A234907

In Column B, a series of Data Like the below:

SP120035_SDP3_Phase4 - 54685

SP120035_SDP3_Phase4 - 54860

Talk_Jan_FA

SP120035_SDP3_Phase4 - 54862

SP120035_SDP3_Phase4 - 54865

SP120035_SDP3_Phase4 - 54995

**A230405**-19542 - Samsung_STMS

A230412-19542 - Samsung_STMS

**A233273**-19542 - Samsung_STMS

As you can see, Only the Bolded texts in column A exists in column B. For the rows the colmun A rows, I want to highlight those rows that their Dara exists in column B. Would appreciate your Help!

Comment: Is this a SQL question? Excel? DataTables? Something else entirely? It's hard to tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This should only bring back tableA records that have the start of tableB with the same values

```
select tableA.* 
from tableA inner join tableB on (tableA.col1 = substring(tableB.col1,1,7))
```